# What is this thing I found in my wiring closet?

Tags: networking

Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask this.

My house is wired with Cat 5e, which is currently exposed as RJ11, which I want to switch to RJ45. I found this little guy in my wiring closet:

[image]

There are 7 cables going into the bottom from throughout the house, and an 8th into the top. The 8th is labeled HR, which I assume stands for home run -- there is a similarly labeled coaxial cable that leads to the telephone pole. I'm not sure where it would go in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. As the FAQ states, "anything in a home setting" isn't on topic here. You may wish to visit our sister sites [diy.se] and [su] and check their respective FAQ's and search to see if your question would be a better fit there.

Comment: Its a punchdown block, which is where communication wires coming in from the outside get punched down to make connections to the communication wires feeding the various wall jacks in your house. It can also be used to "connect" the communication wires in one part of the house to the communication wires in a different part of the house. It is, for all intents and purposes, a distribution point for the communication lines throughout the house. What do you mean with your statement "My house is wired with Cat 5e, which is currently exposed as RJ11, which I want to switch to RJ45"?

Comment: Sorry about that, Michael. Should have read the FAQ.

Comment: @joeqwerty and OP: Just as a comment, it looks like the Cat 5e was run with RJ11 as phone lines, not data lines.  You would need to cut the ends from the block and the other end, and reterminate the cables correctly for data runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a punchdown block most likely used for analog telephone lines.

Comment: I've successfully ran 100Base-T through one of these in a pinch. Not recommended, but possible if the run isn't too long.